# How do I echo individual product information?

Tags: php, arrays, opencart

I'm currently using opencart version 1.5.5.1 with a heavily modified layout.

My problem is I need to echo prices and special prices for specific products on information based pages.

So:

Product 1 £(show the price with product id 1) £(show the special price with product id 1)
Product 2 £(show the price with product id 2) £(show the special price with product id 2)

Do I need to make any changes to the model or controller files or will i be able to do it from within the tpl files?

Many Thanks for taking your time to read this.

EDIT

So what I have so far,

```
<?php if ($product['product_id'] == 1) { ?>
          <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
          <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product_id['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product_id['special']; ?></span>
          <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I've found this from another website but it wont echo anything on a category page, I just get an undefined variable product error.

I've also tried setting the data in the controller file

```
$product = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct(1);
```

but After I have built the array I'm not sure how to work with the data itself.

ANSWERED

OK so I worked it out no need to touch the model or controller files.

Simply add the following code to your view files.

```
$productnumber1 = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct(1); echo $productnumber1['price'];
```

Hope this helps if anyone has the same problem as I did, also to add UK VAT to your price just change the second line to

```
echo $productnumber1['price'] * 1.2;
```

Comment: What have you got so far? Can you post your code?

Comment: `echo "individual product information";` ... sry, had to do it. :D If you want more help, post some of your code.

Comment: If anyone is reading this and has the same/similar problem, please do not implement it this incorrect way. 1. TPL files are only templates, they shouldn't access models directly! 2. There is better and recommended way of calculating the price with taxes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that product information is passed to a view in an array....

```
$products[0]['product_price'];
$products[0]['product_special_price'];
$products[1]['product_price'];
$products[1]['product_special_price'];
```

etc...

Which assumes it follows this format:

```
$ProductArray[ProductNumber]['NameOfInfomrationToShow']
```

Hopefully this will help point you in the right direction.

You may be required to edit the model, which will be fetching the product information from a database to include both those price fields, should it not fetch them by default.